# JavaScript random generate time in 12-hour format

Tags: javascript

I tried to random generate time in 12 hours format. Here is my code in Javascript:

```
randomTime = (hrs, mins) => {
  hrs = Math.round(Math.random()*hrs);
  mins = Math.round(Math.random()*mins);    
  var hFormat = (hrs<10 ? "0" : "");
  var mFormat = (mins<10 ? "0" : "");
  var amPm = (hrs<12 ? "AM" : "PM");
  return String(hFormat+hrs+ ":" +mFormat+mins+ " " +amPm);
}
```

The part where I execute to random generate time:

```
var myDate = new Date();
var hour = myDate.getUTCHours();
var minute = myDate.getMinutes();

var resultTime = this.randomTime(hour, minute);
```

I tried to loop 30 times but the **minute** printed out is only either in 00 or 01 etc. The hour is working fine as I get some values like 9.00AM, 12.00PM etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: I ran this code which is giving random minutes also

Comment: But how come mine is either 00 or 01? Is it according to the system clock?

Comment: I have copied to JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9tr0se5s/. I don't see any issues

Comment: @Vineesh Yeah but the strange thing is I random generated 100 records, all of them are either in 00 or 01 minute which I have no idea why also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't mix the current date in your answer. This gives results that are not purely random. Use this:

```
randomTime = () => {
  hrs = Math.round(Math.random() * 24);
  mins = Math.round(Math.random() * 60);    
  var hFormat = (hrs<10 ? "0" : "");
  var mFormat = (mins<10 ? "0" : "");
  var amPm = (hrs<12 ? "AM" : "PM");
  var is12 = (hrs % 12 === 0);

  return amPm === "AM" && !is12 ? String(hFormat+hrs+ ":" +mFormat+mins+ " " +amPm)
                : "AM" && is12  ? String(12 + ":" +mFormat+mins+ " " +amPm)
                : is12 ? String(hFormat+hrs+ ":" +mFormat+mins+ " " +amPm)
                : String(hFormat+(hrs-12)+ ":" +mFormat+mins+ " " +amPm);

}

var resultTime = this.randomTime();
console.log(resultTime);
```

**Note:**

It can be a pain to do the exact right formatting, making sure that it displays *12:03AM* instead of *00:03AM*, for example. This is why, as an exercise, these are great to do by hand with vanilla javascript, however, in production, it is generally wiser to use libraries like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: do you think it can produce 'PM' hour?

Comment: Glad to hear! You can press the V to the left of my answer to accept the vote :)

Comment: @marzelin, thanks for your hint, I'll adjust it right away

Comment: Oh right, I did not notice that it was all in AM hahah

Comment: @EmmaHannah I adjusted the 12 to 24, to include `PM`, with thanks to @marzelin

Comment: @Sventies But that becomes a problem because I am getting value like 16.46 PM, 20.49 PM, should not them be like 4.46 PM and 8.49 PM instead?

Comment: @Sventies Hmm any idea? Because I could not get it working :(

Comment: @EmmaHannah I have it working, now, but this is where you start to realise why people are so happy with libraries like moment.js: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @Sventies I see I see. I was about to ask about the is12 variable. Now then I notice your note. Thanks so much for all the helps!!!!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't pass int he current time. You were limiting the minutes to the current number of minutes past the hour when the function runs. Try this with hours limited to 12 and minutes limited to 60.

```js
randomTime = () => {
  hrs = Math.round(Math.random()*12);
  mins = Math.round(Math.random()*60);    
  var hFormat = (hrs<10 ? "0" : "");
  var mFormat = (mins<10 ? "0" : "");
  var amPm = (hrs<12 ? "AM" : "PM");
  return String(hFormat+hrs+ ":" +mFormat+mins+ " " +amPm);
}

var resultTime = this.randomTime();
console.log( resultTime );
```

**Edit** @Sventies beat me to this, go upvote him

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'm sorry - I didn't notice. Here, I'll up vote you!